# MySQL ALTER TABLE ORDER BY f1 DESC - Does this block SELECT queries?

Tags: mysql, locking, sql-order-by, alter

I have a MySQL MYISAM table (say tbl) consisting of 2 unsigned int fields, say, f1 and f2. There is an index on f2 and the table is very large (approximately 320,000,000+ rows). I update this table periodically (with approximately 100,000 new rows a week), and, in order to be able to search this table without doing an ORDER BY (which would be very time consuming in real-time queries), I physically ORDER the table according to the way in which I want to retrieve its rows.

So, I perform an ALTER TABLE tbl ORDER BY f1 DESC. (I know I have enough physical space on the server for a copy of the table.) I have read that during this operation, a temporary table is created and SELECT statements are not affected on the current rows.

However, I have experienced that this is not the case, and SELECT statements on the table that occur at the same time with the ALTER table are getting blocked and do not terminate. After the ALTER TABLE tbl completes (about 40 minutes on the production server), the SELECT statements on tbl start executing fine again.

Is there any reason why the "ALTER table tbl ORDER BY f1 DESC" seems to be blocking other clients from querying tbl?

Answer (score 0):

Altering a table will always grab a lock on the table, preventing SELECTs from running.

I'll admin that I didn't even know you could do that with an ALTER TABLE.

What are you trying to get from the table? For example, all records in a given range? 320 million rows is not a trivial number. I'll give you my gut reactions:

1. Switch to InnoDB (allows #2, also gives transactions, but without #2 may hurt performance)
2. Partition the table (makes it act like a number of slightly smaller tables)
3. Consider a redesign, such as having a "working set" table and a "historical" table, basically manually partitioning. If you usually look for recently inserted data, this (along with partitioning) will help a lot. If your lookups are evenly distributed, this probably won't make a difference.
4. Consider adding a new column you could use in conjunction to narrow down selects (so instead of searching on date, search on date and customer ID)

Since I don't know what you're storing, some of these (such as #4) may not apply.

There are some other things you could try. OPTIMIZE TABLE may help you but take less time, but I doubt it. I think internally it's implemented as a dump/reload, at least on the InnoDB side.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will explore InnoDB partitioning in more detail.